# How can I convert fastai image from open_image() format to opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, fast-ai

I have image opened this way in fast.ai:

```
 img = open_image(img_f)
```

How do I show it with **cv2.imshow** ?

Comment: It needs to be a Numpy array, for `cv2.imshow()`, so try `cv2.imshow("preview",img)` followed by `cv2.waitKey()`. Failing that, try `cv2.imshow("preview",np.array(img))`

Comment: both fail with TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mat'

Comment: `cv2.imshow("image",image2np(img))`

Comment: isn't that FastAi already uses this package ;)

Comment: @StepanYakovenko, fastai uses OpenCV by default because it is the fastest library out there. Can you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

FastAi already uses this package to work with images.
When you do open_image function check the doc string:

```
def open_image(fn):
    """ Opens an image using OpenCV given the file path.
```